# Flume to load data to local file system

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am using hadoop 2.2 in linux.Can any one tell me how to use fileroll in flume.I know that fileroll sends data to local file system.Can anyone tell me how???

Thanks in advance..

Comment: please, add your try or the part you dont understand. dont just ask people to do things for you

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the file roll sink, you need only configure the sink in the flume configuration file. This config file example will fetch data from a spooling directory source located in the directory `/logs/source`, send it through a memory channel to a file roll sink in directory `/logs/sink`.

There are other configuration options you should have a look at in the flume user's guide [here](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

```
# Define a memory channel called ch1 on agent1
agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory

agent1.sources.spool.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.spool.channels = ch1
agent1.sources.spool.spoolDir = /logs/source
agent1.sources.spool.fileHeader = true

agent1.sinks.fr1.type = file_roll
agent1.sinks.fr1.channel = ch1
agent1.sinks.fr1.sink.directory = /logs/sink

agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sources = spool
agent1.sinks = fr1
```

Comment: @deanosaur...can u tell me how to download the data from twitter to local file system..